# ServiceStack with IdentityServer4 intergration

Tags: servicestack, identityserver4

I couldn't find answers about using both frameworks working together.

We are planning to build an identity provider service (like Google Account) which is used to authenticate a user and provide OpenId Connection protocol to a Rely Party app. We have existing projects built in ServiceStack which work all fine. However, ServiceStack seems not to be compatible with IdentityServer4 in regards to authenticating a user. ServiceStack has its own authentication mechanism and IdentityServer4 relies on Asp.NET Identity Model. If I sign in via ASP.NET Identity Model, ServiceStack APIs may not recognize the user has signed in. And vice versa.

Is there any suggestion about this is a dead end or some solution that may make them work together?

Answer (score 0):

The [mvcidentityserver](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/mvcidentityserver) Project Template contains a pre-configured ServiceStack + IdentityServer4 starting project template:

```
$ dotnet tool install -g x

$ x new mvcidentityserver ProjectName
```

See the [Using IdentityServer4 Auth in ServiceStack](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-identityserver) docs for more info on ServiceStack + IdentityServer4 integration.

In addition there are a couple of options available from the ServiceStack community:

- [Using IdentityServer 4 with ServiceStack and Angular](http://estynedwards.com/blog/2016/01/30/ServiceStack-IdentityServer-Angular/)
- [servicestack-authentication-identityserver](https://github.com/wwwlicious/servicestack-authentication-identityserver)
- [JwtAuthProviderReaderPatchedForIdentityServer4.cs](https://gist.github.com/tobiaszuercher/bd38241975dcbe0adda2ccc2ba547d04) - [description](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/identityserver-integration-possible-with-jwtauthproviderreader-but-needs-small-adjustment/4281)